# Get ServiceWorkerGlobalScope's variable from window context

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have a service worker in `sw.js`, it uses a template engine to get the commit numbre as a version number. I set the cache name like this:

```
var version = {{ commit_hash }};
self.cacheName = `cache-` + version;
```

I have some scripts being added to the cache on the worker's install, but there are scripts that are dynamically loaded on the page. I would like to load all the scripts/css on the first load without forcing the user to wait for the app to install first.

I can get all the content on the page with the following code in the bottom of `index.html`:

```
var toCache = ['/'];

var css = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
for(el of css) {
    var href = el.getAttribute("href");
    if(href) {
        toCache.push(href);
    }
}
var js = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
for(el of js) {
    var src = el.getAttribute("src");
    if(src) {
        toCache.push(src);
    }
}
```

That works fine, now I would just need to open the correct cache, fetch files that aren't already present, and store them. Something like:

```
toCache.forEach(function(url) {
    caches.match(url).then(function(result) {
        if(!result) {
            fetch(url).then(function(response) {
                caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
                    cache.put(url, response)
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Is there a way to get the cacheName from the service worker inside a script tag in a different file?

And yes, I know that I could simplify this greatly by doing the check in the for/of loops. I broke it apart so it would be easier to describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this](http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html#.WyPm5Z9Ki9I) blog I was able to pass messages from the service worker and back. First, I added the following function at the top of `sw.js`:

```
function clientPostMessage(client, message){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var channel = new MessageChannel();

        channel.port1.onmessage = function(event){
            if(event.data.error){
                reject(event.data.error);
            }
            else {
                resolve(event.data);
            }
        };

        client.postMessage(message, [channel.port2]);
    });
}
```

This allows my service worker to post a message to the window, and then do a callback with a promise.

Then, in my `index.html` file I added the following to a script tag:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
    switch(event.data) {
        case "addAll":
            var toCache = [];
            var css = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
            for(el of css) {
                var href = el.getAttribute("href");
                if(href) {
                    toCache.push(href);
                }
            }
            var js = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
            for(el of js) {
                var src = el.getAttribute("src");
                if(src) {
                    toCache.push(src);
                }
            }
            event.ports[0].postMessage(toCache);
            break;
        default:
            console.log(event.data);
    }
});
```

This listens to any service workers asking for messages, and if it is a "addAll" message, it will get all the scripts and linked content on the page and return an array of the scripts.

Finally, I added the following to my `activate` event listener function in `sw.js`:

```
// Get all the clients, and for each post a message
clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
    clients.forEach(client => {
        // Post "addAll" to get a list of files to cache
        clientPostMessage(client, "addAll").then(message => {
            // For each file, check if it already exists in the cache
            message.forEach(url => {
                caches.match(url).then(result => {
                    // If there's nothing in the cache, fetch the file and cache it
                    if(!result) {
                        fetch(url).then(response => {
                            caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
                                cache.put(url, response);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    })
});
```

For all clients the service worker sends an "addAll" message to the page and gets the result. For each item in the result, it checks if the value is already in the cache and if not, fetches and adds it.
With this method, the install listener of the service worker only needs to contain:

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    if(self.skipWaiting) {
        self.skipWaiting();
    }
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/',
                '/index.html',
            ])
        })
    );
});
```

It seems to be working well so far, if anyone has any suggestions or sees any errors I'd be happy to hear! You can also tell me how improper this is, but it makes my life a lot easier for adding service workers for pre-existing projects that rely on scripts that aren't bundled together.

Answer (score 0):

No.

JavaScript executing in the window context cannot access SW's context and vice versa. You have to implement a workaround of some sort.

Remember that you can use postMessage to communicate between the two.

Comment: Thank you! I found [this](http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html#.WyPm5Z9Ki9I) awesome blog post and was able to pass values from the sw to the window. I'll add a more detailed answer with my methods :)